# Semi-transparent element visible (in Chrome) over opaque background of same color

Tags: css

I'm placing a transparent grey box over some labels when their associated checkbox is checked.  The box is the same color as the background, but partially transparent.

If I was to do something like this in Photoshop or Illustrator, the semi-transparent box would not be visible, as it would blend in perfectly with the background.

But in most browsers I tested, (Chrome, Brave, Epic, Vivaldi, Firefox, Waterfox) the box appears slightly darker than the background.

Of the browsers I have available on this machine, only Safari displayed the box the way I expected.

Any ideas how I can make it blend in perfectly in all browsers?

Here's my code:

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(51,51,51);
  color: white;
  padding:30px;
}
div#checklist input[type=checkbox] + label::before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0%;
  height: 1.2em;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
}
div#checklist {
  position: relative;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
div#checklist input[type=checkbox]:checked + label::before {
  content: '';
  background-color: rgba(51,51,51,.7);
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="checklist">
  <input type="checkbox" name="seo-1" id="seo-1"value="seo-1"><label for="seo-1"> first item
  </label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="seo-2" id="seo-2"value="seo-2"><label for="seo-2"> second item
  </label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="seo-3" id="seo-3"value="seo-3"><label for="seo-3"> third item
  </label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="seo-4" id="seo-4"value="seo-4"><label for="seo-4"> fourth item
  </label><br>
</div>
```

Edit: I ended up not needing to do this, but I'm still curious why a semi-transparent box would be visible over an opaque background of the same color.

Comment: Reason you are including the `background-color: rgba(51,51,51,.7);` on top of body background (`background-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);`). You can try applying font color to make it looks like disabled(lighter color). Also the `width:100%` is introducing horizontal scroll. Check that out.

Comment: @Selvam Thanks for pointing out the horizontal scroll bit.  I added `position: relative; overflow-x: hidden;` to the container.

Answer (score 0):

Try below

```css
div#checklist input[type=checkbox]:checked + label::before {
    content: '';
    background-color: rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.24);
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: No good.  All this does is make a much lighter box that's even more visible.